# How can I determine whether the current window in Vim was opened in a new tab?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, autocmd

In Vim, I use the [Startify](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-startify) plugin. There's a few ways to open new Vim tabs with this plugin; and I would like to configure my Vim to ensure that `:tcd %:h` is executed automatically for the first buffer opened into a new Tab after executing Startify.

For purposes like this, Startify provides the [`StartifyBufferOpened`](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-startify/blob/05122f08/doc/startify.txt#L713-L739) autocmd. Unfortunately, this is executed for *every* buffer that you open with Startify. Similarly, I'm aware of Vim's built-in [`TabNew`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/autocmd.html#TabNew); but this fires *any* time a new tabpage is created; I only want to `:tcd` in the tabpages created by Startify.

Is there a VimScript function I could construct that would, when evaluated in several new buffers (i.e. by `StartifyBufferOpened`), only actually run a particular command *if a new tabpage was just created for that buffer?*

Comment: Is it a performance problem to do `:tcd` for every buffer? Unrelated: if I pop 2 buffers in a tab, which directory should I use?

Comment: `if winnr('$') == 1 | tcd %:h | endif`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Ah, if it was unclear, I specifically wanted to set the working-directory by the *first* buffer opened into a new tab, and leave it unmodified by later buffers opened into that tab (including my own window-managmement post-Startify)